# Embed one Coxeter System into another

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, coxeter-groups

What is a good reference that explains all the braid relations and diagrams for Coxeter systems concisely?

In particular, how do I embed $H_3$ inside $D_6$, or $H_4$ inside $E_8$? Any hints?